# Response not updating in Postman/Insomnia NextJs App

Tags: npm, next.js, request, postman, response

I am getting started with **NextJs** development. I have created a **Module** named **Auth** and its corresponding **Controller** and **Service/Provider**(Code Provided Below). The issue is when I **start** the **Nest server** using `npm run start`, **Postman** gives the correct and updated **response** to my **Requests**

```
Request (Get): http//:localhost:3333/auth/signin
Response: "I have signed up+ Give me logic"
```

But while **server** is **still running**, if i change the response return text, let's say "I have signed up.... Give me logic....", the Postman still gives the old "I have signed up+ Give me logic" response value. Expected was the updated one i.e "I have signed up.... Give me logic...."

```
After updating... same response
Request (Get): http//:localhost:3333/auth/signin
Response: "I have signed up+ Give me logic"
```

**Postman** gives me **updated** response only when i **restart** the server. I can't restart the server every time to see update response to a request. Can anyone guide me? Thanks.

/src/auth/**auth.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthController } from "./auth.controller";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Module({
    controllers:[AuthController],
    providers:[AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule{}
```

/src/auth/**auth.controller.ts**

```js
import { Controller, Post, Get } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController{
    constructor (private authService:AuthService){}
    
    @Post('signup')
    signupPost(){return this.authService.signup()}
  
    @Post('signin')
    signinPost(){return this.authService.signin()}
  
    @Get('signup')
    signupGet(){return this.authService.signup()}
  
    @Get('signin')
    signinGet(){return this.authService.signin()}
}
```

/src/auth/**auth.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable({})
export class AuthService{
    signup(){
        return "I have signed up+ Give me logic"
    }
    signin(){
        return "I have signed in- Give me logic"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by starting the **server** in **dev mode**

```
npm run start:dev
```

not this

```
npm run start
```